# Postgresql Multiple insertions into any tables depending on result of one select

Tags: postgresql

Using Postgresql (9.6) i need to execute multiple insert queries into any tables (***table1, table2, table3, ...***) depending on result of one select query from another ***tableMain*** if result has one or more records, like:

```
{
 insert into table1 (id, name) values(1, 'name');
 insert into table2 (id, name) values(1, 'name');
 insert into table3 (id, name) values(1, 'name');
} if exists (select id from tableMain where id = 1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [data modifying CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING) that first checks if the row in tablemain exists, and then re-uses that result in subsequent INSERT statements.

```
with idcheck (main_exist) as (
  select exists (select * from tablemain where id = 1 limit 1)
), t1 as (
  insert into table1 (id, name)
  select 1, 'name'
  from idcheck 
  where main_exists
), t2 as (
  insert into table2 (id, name)
  select 1, 'name'
  from idcheck 
  where main_exists
)
insert into table3 (id, name)
select 1, 'name'
from idcheck 
where main_exists;
```

If you always want to insert the same values in all three tables, you can include those values in the first query so that you don't need to repeat them:

```
with idcheck (id, name, main_exist) as (
  select 1, 
         'name',
         exists (select * from tablemain where id = 1 limit 1)
), t1 as (
  insert into table1 (id, name)
  select id, name
  from idcheck 
  where main_exists
), t2 as (
  insert into table2 (id, name)
  select id, name
  from idcheck 
  where main_exists
)
insert into table3 (id, name)
select id, name
from idcheck 
where main_exists;
```

Comment: This helped. Thanks.